# Sorting a 2D arraylist based on first element of nested arraylist

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, 2d

I'm having an issue whereby the original 2D arraylist, after sorting, outputs in the following format:

```
[639.5, 134, -2]
[639.524, 131, -1]
[640.478, 179, -2]
[647.968, 192, -2]
[649.068, 199, -2]
[65.581, 3, -1]
[66.387, 6, -1]
[66.726, 7, -1]
[660.182, 194, -1]
```

and I'd like to sort based on the first column only. Hence, my expected result should be this instead:

```
[65.581, 3, -1]
[66.387, 6, -1]
[66.726, 7, -1]
[639.5, 134, -2]
[639.524, 131, -1]
[640.478, 179, -2]
[647.968, 192, -2]
[649.068, 199, -2]
[660.182, 194, -1]
```

Somehow the `Collections.sort()` method sorts the list as if it's a String, hence "0" is bigger than ".", not knowing that the first column is made up of double values. Can anyone assist me in this? Thanks!

Comment: Could we see the code that you're using to sort this data? it would help. Maybe in [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com)?

Comment: this is the original unsorted 2D arraylist: http://pastebin.com/aUaHaNdL note that every line is an element in the parent arraylist. and every line has an arraylist of 3 elements. that's how we get the 2D arraylist. i ended up with this after using Collections.sort... http://pastebin.com/PaxjQQS2 i'm doing this in java.

Comment: I was more going for the code where you create, modify, and sort the list, but that is helpful. :P Most likely, you will end up having to create your own sort function. [Here's a blog post where someone appears to be doing what you want.](http://publicmind.in/blog/sorting-2d-array-java/)

Comment: the original list and sorted list are in this format:
ArrayList<ArrayList> originalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<ArrayList> finalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

the whole code has pretty much redundant info, so i hope this will do. heh.

Comment: My code's here, with the sort method at the bottom, where I've removed my non-working codes...

http://pastebin.com/zpp1Zw1G

Answer (score 2):

Use Double.compare() method....
Pass that first column value in this method it will work...

For example :

In main file :

```
 Collection.sort(arraylist variable,new PositionComparator());
```

Other Class :

```
public class PositionComparator implements Comparator ArrayList<ArrayList> {
    public int compare(ArrayList<ArrayList> o1, ArrayList<ArrayList> o2) {
        double val1, val2;
        val1 = Double.parseDouble(o1.get("your first value"));
        val2 = Double.parseDouble(o2.get("your second value"));
        return Double.compare(val1, val2);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: i'm pretty much an idiot when it comes to hashmap and stuff, could you take a look at my code here? the bottom method is where i intend to sort. i've deleted my non-working codes there.

http://pastebin.com/zpp1Zw1G

Comment: hey i am here to help you...not here to write code for you...at least try once...and if stuck den i will help...

Comment: See the edited code once again....and try it once...you will definitely do that...

Comment: i encounter this error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method sort(java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList>,PositionComparator)
  location: interface java.util.Collection

Comment: i think your Collection.sort(arraylist variable,new PositionComparator()); has the input of a 1D arraylist instead of 2D. mine is a 2D.

Comment: ohk...give the code where you want to sort....not whole code as you given...because its take too much time 2 see it so...

Comment: http://ifile.it/3qhm8au

it's a netbeans project with the source files.
you may take a look at Line 153 which prints out "list2" for your understanding. the end result should be a sorted "list2" with the sorting rules as per original topic.

the whole code's linked somehow, but i guess the portion of concern is only in the sorting method in Line 149, because i've declared the list to be sorted as a global 2D arraylist.

Comment: i can't open your project because this site is not accessible to me as i am in company...

Comment: sorting method: http://pastebin.com/ciL8PJdm

http://pastebin.com/XYn6aYpf --> link containing contents of list2

Comment: hey dude...write some code in it yaar....though it will doing by string...its ok.. but write something so that i can understand...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DqaBN05t --> this is what i did and it ended up with the wrong sorting order as it sorts by string.

Comment: i have the following errors... :( http://i42.tinypic.com/6rr5w7.png http://i40.tinypic.com/1z6tq9.png

Answer (score 0):

Collection.sort orders the list in its natural order so you might want to try overriding the compareTo() method

Comment: yea i read that somewhere. i'm not sure how to go about doing what you suggested. :( i can do this easily in excel, but i would rather have the whole program be running in java without the need to post-process in excel halfway.